# Не выровнены ссылки при просмотре ревизий

Tags: дефект, дизайн, ревизии

При просмотре [ревизий вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/572438/revisions) нарушен горизонтальный интервал между "ссылка" и "полностью":

> [image: ссылка полностью]

Может быть и такой [вариант](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4072/revisions):

> [image: полностью]